# Автозагрузка DataGridView в C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio

Есть поле DataGridView. Как реализовать автозагрузку данных в это поле при запуске программы?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=C:\\Users\\monte\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\bib (2).accdb";
        public int act_table = 1; //Активная таблица (1 - Авторы, 2 - Города, 3 - Издательства, 4 - Книги, 5 - Разделы, 6 - Читатели)
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            string CommandText = "SELECT " +
    "[Обращения].[Номер билета], " +
    "[Книги].[Код книги], " +
    "[Книги].[Название], " +
    "[Обращения].[Дата выдачи], " +
    "[Обращения].[Плановая дата возврата], " +
    "[Читатели].[Фамилия], " +
    "[Читатели].[Имя], " +
    "[Книги].[Стоимость проката день], " +
    "[Авторы].[ФИО] " +
  "FROM " +
    "[Обращения], " +
    "[Книги], " +
    "[Читатели], " +
    "[Авторы] " +
  "WHERE " +
    "([Обращения].[Код книги]=[Книги].[Код книги]) AND " +
    "([Читатели].[Номер читательского билета] = [Обращения].[Номер билета]) AND " +
    "([Книги].[Автор] = [Авторы].[Код автора]) ";

            if (textBox1.Text != "")  // если набран текст в поле фильтра
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0) // Название книги
                    CommandText = CommandText + " AND (Книги.[Название] = '" + textBox1.Text + "')";
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) // Фамилия читателя
                    CommandText = CommandText + " AND (Читатели.[Фамилия] LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%') ";
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2) // ФИО Автора
                    CommandText = CommandText + " AND ([Авторы].[ФИО] LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%') ";
            }

            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(CommandText, ConnectionString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "[Книги]");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Книги]"].DefaultView;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            button1_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: запихните вызов в form_load

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, можно поподробнее, пожалуйста. Что и как, я должен вызвать?

Comment: я так понял у вас щас все работает, только по нажатию на кнопку, верно?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, именно

Comment: ну вам либо в `program.cs` писать...с него начинается старт, либо просто навести на евент при загрузке формы...назвается form_load